# When would it be useful to implement Iterator but not Iterable?

Tags: java, iterator

When would it be useful to implement iterator without implementing iterable?

Or is implementing iterator simply a by product of implementing iterable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two are related but not the same.

A `List` is `Iterable` - you can get its `Iterator`. It is **not** an `Iterator`.

An `Iterator` is a single use class that can iterate along a `Collection` of objects using the `hasNext` and `next` methods.

An `Iterable` is a `Collection` class that returns an `Iterator` instance when then the `iterator()` method is called.

I would go as far as to say that I see **no** case where an `Iterable` should `implements Iterator`. And as a `Iterator` is single use I cannot see a case where `Iterator` should `implements Iterable`.

Comment: `List` has `ListIterator` which extends `Iterator`. So why "It is not an `Iterator`"?

Comment: List implements iterable and has an inner implementation of iterator correct? I am wondering about an implementation of iterator with no iterable implementation.

Comment: @ferrerverck `List` _returns_ an `Iterator` because it is `Iterable`. It is certainly not an `Iterator` - that is the the job of the `ListIterator`.

Comment: @graviton A database `ResultSet`. This is an `Iterator` pattern but it does not have an `Iterable`, it is the result of a query.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't understand. From official docs: `public interface ListIterator<E> extends Iterator<E>`. Why ListIterator is not an Iterator?

Comment: @ferrerverck `ListIterator` is surely and `Iterator` but it is not a `List` and is not `Iterable`. These are two entirely different classes, no?

Comment: @ferrerverck - I believe Boris is saying that List itself is not an iterator (it does not implement iterator). It does implement iterable, thus it is an iterable, iterable requires a method that returns an iterator, thus it has an inner implementation, so its method returns an iterator, but it in itself is not an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you'd implement either an Iterable or an Iterator to hide the implementation of a collection from the code that's iterating over the collection.  Either one would work well.  The difference lies in how many times the collection can be traversed.  An iterator can only traverse the collection once while the Iterable can traverse the collection many times.  You can traverse the Iterable by asking it for an Iterator and you can do that multiple times.

Comment: So do you know of an example where I would want a class to implement iterator without iterable? As in, when would it be necessary / more useful to only transverse a collection once?

Comment: +1. The repeatability, or lack thereof, is the important difference. Consider reading lines from a network connection. It's a perfectly sensible Iterator, but making it Iterable doesn't work. What should happen if the caller calls iterator() a second time?

Answer (score 0):

They are very similar in semantics and use cases, but differ in implementation. Iterable is a simple factory for Iterators which can be used inside for loops. For this reason it's might be more convenient to implement an Iterable.

```
for(String s : getIterable()){
    ...
}
```

Versus:

```
Iterator<String> it = getIterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
    String s = it.next();
    ...
}
```

However, in some case Iterator might not be re-instantiated, i.e. when you're running through a db request results, so in this case you can't make it Iterable without re-sending your request.