# Confusion about collections, enumeration, and iterator in Java

Tags: java, collections, enums, iterator, enumeration

My textbook barely talks about enumeration in Java, and the videos that I've watched don't explain much. So from what I'm understanding, enumeration is like a whole different class 
where you can store constants in. Can someone expand to me about the constants and perhaps 
show me better examples? Like I understand what constants are after seeing the examples 
such as colors, directions, and in the previous videos it was people, while in the enum 
version of one my projects during the school year, it was command words. But I don't 100% 
understand the concept or how to use.

2. Also, what's the point of an Enumeration when you can just make a collection? Like for 
   instance, the last video i saw, the video maker made enums of people in the format of 
   name(String description, int age), and that's how he defined his constructor and he had 
   get and set methods. What's the advantage of doing this rather than just creating a person 
   object in the same exact way and them creating a collection and storing person objects in 
   there?
3. I went to look up the above, and after seeing this thread:
   [Difference between Java Enumeration and Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948194/difference-between-java-enumeration-and-iterator)
   An iterator is something that will let me loop through a collection, and all this time I 
   thought enumeration was something like a different class. But in the thread they're 
   comparing them. Enumeration is just something like an iterator, but without the remove 
   method. Is this enumeration something different than what I was talking about above?

Comment: Go read the javadoc for `Iterator` and `Enumeration`.

Comment: And an "enum" is not the same as an "Enumeration".

Comment: You are getting confused between an `enum` and an `Enumeration`. An `enum` is a special type of singleton class whereas an `Enumeration` is a deprecated `Iterator` pattern. Forget about `Enumeration`.

Comment: Whenever you have `public static int SOMETHING=0; public static int SOMETHINGELSE=1;` etc and then use `SOMETHING` completely seperately from the `0` it's stored as you can formalise that as an enum

Comment: I read enum types before, and I just looked over it, and I'm still unsure of when to use over a collection, as I don't seem to understand it. And I've read iterator before and right now as well. The java docs for enumeration is very much like the one for iterator, but that's where I'm confused...is enumeration at all related to enum types?

Comment: @Abdul No, `Enumeration` is not related to `enum`. As Boris said, forget about `Enumeration`, as `Iterator` has essentially replaced it. As for `enum` vs. `Collection`s, an `enum` is better used for static, constant data, whereas a `Collection` is better for dynamically produced and/or changing data.

Comment: So, if I have a bunch of things who's value isn't going to be changed, and that I want to be used universally (that's why it's static?) I'd use an enum. Am I correct?

Comment: @Abdul More or less. An `enum` is useful for, as Boris' answer basically says, enumerating constants. It is useful for containing a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) of distinct but related constants that are [enumerated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerate). So an `enum` for the cardinal compass directions (North, South, East, West) would be a good use case. The scope (universal or otherwise) would depend on your application design. I feel that my explanation may be a bit lacking. Does it make sense?

Comment: There was something else I was wondering an hour ago, but unfortunately I forgot, but your explanation as well as Boris' is clear and helpful. Thank you. Unfortunately I can't add to rep as mine isn't 15 yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confused between several different classes.

1. `enum`
2. `Enumeration`
3. `Iterator`

An `enum` is an **enumerated constant**, i.e. a constant that can take several defined values such as

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE,
    FEMALE;
}
```

It is designed to provide type safety.

An `Enumeration` is a now deprecated part of the `Collection`s API - forget about this. It is superseded by `Iterator`.

An `Iterator` is an implementation of the Iterator Pattern as described by the Gang of Four.

For why to use an `Iterator` rather than a `Collection` maybe my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20454741/2071828) will help.

As for *enums of people in the format of name(String description, int age), and that's how he defined his constructor and he had get and set methods*. This is a big no-no.

An `enum` should be a constant so should not have `setter` methods. An `enum` is a set of defined values like in my example above.

If you want a `Collection` of `people` then a `Person` class in a `Collection<Person>` would be the correct solution.

So, in summary. Use an `enum` for constant values; use a `Collection` for, well, collections of things. And do not use an `Enumeration` - forget it exists at all.

Comment: I think the last point to address is confusion between use cases for `enum` vs `Collection`.

Comment: when you say type safety, it's because you don't have to define what types the constant are in an enum correct?

Comment: @Abdul if I have a method `setGender(final int gender)` I can pass in any valid `int` - say `2,000`. This means it is up to the program to check validity. If I have a method `setGender(final Gender gender)` I can **only** pass in `Gender.MALE` or `Gender.FEMALE` - I have turned `Gender` into its own **type**. This is type safety.

Comment: ohhhh I see. You're making your own data type. Thank you.

Comment: @Abdul please accept the answer if it answered your question. Thanks.