# Why Collections.enumeration comes with enumeration() method

Tags: java, collections, enumeration

In Collections Framework, we have the `Iterator` and `ListIterator` interfaces, which are used for iterating data structures. They provide full functionality for iteration. But I wonder that why the JDK has an `enumeration()` method on the `Collections` class.

Can anyone explain this point to me?

Comment: Reopened because, while the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707657/confusion-about-collections-enumeration-and-iterator-in-java) talks a lot about `Collections` and `Enumeration`, it doesn't actually answer the specific question about the reason for the `Collection.enumeration` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Iterator` and `ListIterator` provide complete facilities to iterate over collections. Indeed, the [documentation for Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) essentially says that `Iterator` has superseded `Enumeration`. Every collection is an `Iterable` and therefore can be iterated using an `Iterator`. Why then is there a method `Collections.enumeration` that produces an `Enumeration` over that collection?

The reason is that `Enumeration` was present in the original Java 1.0 release, and `Iterator` was not introduced until the collections framework was added in 1.2. Thus, there was a body of code and APIs that used `Enumeration`. The `Collections.enumeration` method was added to in order for (then) new collections-based code to adapt to old code that required the use of `Enumeration`.

Comment: Thanks to you Stuart Marks